# Why my menu is fleeing around?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a problem with the HTML and the CSS, where I nested the Salads, Fresh and the Smoothies in Recipes. But hover last one to show and choose to click over them (to choose specific salad or fresh etc.), they have been fleeing me (they show, but I can't click on them), so I can't open the hyperlinks which they contain.
This is the HTML code:

```
 <div id="nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Tips for health</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="lechebni%20isvoistva.html">The healing properties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="5%20vajni%20podpravki.html"5 important spices that you should include in your diet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="loshi%20navici.html">Bad habits and their removal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="vodata.html">Water as a source of life</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="title=">Recipes</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Salads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-nav-list">   
                            <li><a href="zelena%20salata.html">Lettuce</a></li>
                            <li><a href="frenska%20salata.html">French salad</a></li>
                            <li><a href="salata%20cherveno%20cveklo.html">Red Beet Salad</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Fresh</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-nav-list">
                            <li><a href="sweet%20fresh.html">Sweet fresh</a></li>
                            <li><a href="fresh%20za%20detoksikaciq.html">Fresh detox</a></li>
                            <li><a href="citrusov%20fresh.html">Citruc fresh</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <ul class="sub-nav-list">
                        <li><a href="#">Smoothies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul class="sub-sub-nav-list">     
                            <li><a href="smuti%20shokolad.html">Chocolate smoothie</a></li>
                            <li><a href="tropichesko%20smuti.html">Tropical smoothie</a></li>
                            <li><a href="smuti%20banan%20ananas.html">Smoothie with banana and pineapple</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
.sub-nav-list {
  display: none;
}
.sub-sub-nav-list {
  display: none;
}
ul.nav-list li:hover > ul.sub-nav-list {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
ul.nav-list li ul.sub-nav-list:hover + ul.sub-sub-nav-list {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: could you make a JSFidlle for a working demo?

Comment: Yes, I made some -  https://jsfiddle.net/zoyz4sud/3/

Comment: My advice is to learn more deeper about nested lists. As you can see, your html aint right. http://htmldog.com/techniques/dropdowns/

Comment: I try this which is described in the website but did not work as I want, because when I hover the recipes then all the items which have there are show, but I don't want. I want when I hover the recipes, then hover the salads, fresh or smoothies then their items to show and to click them.

Comment: I've fixed the html and try my css and they are: https://jsfiddle.net/zoyz4sud/4/                                                                         What do you think? :)

Comment: Its working now, isnt it? The code looks better!

Comment: Yep it's working and yes is looks better. Thnaks! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked out!

Comment: Me too. And the website you gave me is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <li><a href="lechebni%20isvoistva.html">The healing properties</a></li>
  <li><a href="5%20vajni%20podpravki.html"5 important spices that you should include in your diet</a></li>
```

it should be 
like this

```html
<li><a href="5%20vajni%20podpravki.html">5 important spices that you should include in your diet</a></li>
```

right ?